# "limit" column in Hibernate JPA H2 problem

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, create-table

I have a small SpringBoot JPA REST service.

I'm using H2 for a development environment.

I'm using  `ddl-auto: update`

Using a SINGLE table strategy for hierarchical entities.

Simulation of actual code is like below

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public abstract class SuperEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    private String      property1;
    private String      property2;
    .............
    ...............

    @ManyToOne
    private SomeOtherEntity b;
}
```

There are many Child entities, But one of the entities is like this

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child1")
public class Child1 extends SuperEntity {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CType cType;

    private BigDecimal     limit;
    private BigDecimal     x;
    private BigDecimal     y;
    private int            z;
    .............
    ...............  
}
```

But at the application startup during DDL execution, I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
 CREATE TABLE SUPER_ENTITY (
            .............
            ...............

            LIMIT[*] DECIMAL(19,2),
            .............
            ...............

        ) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

I mentioned only **LIMIT** column because this is where *** is mentioned by H2 error log**.
if I just changed the name of the field in Child1 class from limit to creditLimit, all works fine.

what's the problem having a column name limit?

Comment: Because limit is a reserved keyword (to limit number of records returned by a select). https://razorsql.com/articles/h2_limit_rows.html

Comment: I believe I should've seen that. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan Hey mentioned, 'limit' is a reserved keyword. So you need to escape it like:

```
@Column(name = "`limit`")
```

There are a few more methods. See https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/